# Using blocks in my app causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS only on iOS4.3

Tags: iphone, ios4, objective-c-blocks

I've pasted the example code from [LambdaAlert](https://github.com/zoul/Lambda-Alert/blob/master/Classes/Application.m) into my app and it's generating EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when I run on iOS4.3. The same code works fine in older versions of the OS.

```
  LambdaAlert *alert = [[LambdaAlert alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"Test Alert"
                          message:@"See if the thing works."];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Foo" block:^{ NSLog(@"Foo"); }]; // <-- Crashes here with EXC_BAD_ACCESS no matter what code is in the block (even an empty block!)
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Bar" block:^{ NSLog(@"Bar"); }];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel" block:NULL];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
```

Is there something I need to do differently for iOS4.3?

Comment: I'd contact the author of LambdaAlert.

Comment: It's not specific to that class. I've tried other blocks and it fails in every case.

Comment: How can I start a bounty on this? It seems I can make bounties on any questions but mine.

Comment: Okay, more info. If I run the stock Lambda-Alert demo app in iOS4.3 it works fine so there's something in my projects build settings that's causing this but I really don't know where to begin to find what it is.

Comment: Found the root cause but not sure the fix. In my project's linker flags I have: -weak_library /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib to flurry. If I remove that then it works fine on iOS4.3 but I still need for flurry. Is there a solution that will let iOS4.3 and -weak_library /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib coexist?

Comment: The problem is simply a bug in the iOS Simulator. The codes works fine on the device. I've filled a radar on Apple's bug reporter (radar://9470793)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-weak_library /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib` breaks the iOS Simulator. Use `-weak-lSystem` instead.