# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on objc_setAssociatedObject with -weak_library /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib linker flags

Tags: iphone, ios, exc-bad-access, weak-references

I have a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when I call `objc_setAssociatedObject` with the linker flags : `-weak_library /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib` linker flags.

I absolutely need the linker flag because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313786/ios-4-app-crashes-at-startup-on-ios-3-1-3-symbol-not-found-nsconcretestackblo), do somebody know a workaround?

(I also have a crash on `dispatch_async` but I can work around that... Also, I'm building a iOS 4 only feature on my app that is iOS 3 compatible)

EDIT: With more research, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716555/using-blocks-in-my-app-causes-exc-bad-access-only-on-ios4-3) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981088/strange-issue-due-to-block-support-for-ios-3-1-3) question but no more answer...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is simply a bug in the iOS Simulator. The codes works fine on the device.

I've filled a radar on Apple's bug reporter (radar://9470793)

EDIT: Just found out : `-weak_library /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib breaks the iOS Simulator. Use -weak-lSystem instead.`

Comment: Can anyone explain why that is?  /usr/lib/libSystem.dylib symlinks to /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib.  Or is the crash because it should be using the Simulator SDK's libSystem instead?